# TightVNC Access to 1&1 server denied

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, vnc, tightvnc

I have a Windows 2008 server running at 1&1 provider (1und1). 
Server is inaccessible. It seems a windows update is the culprit.

Hardware reset did not solve it.

Customer support told me to reach the server with VNC Console, but I get this message :

**Error: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "217.72.206.68:5914" "connect,resolve")**

Customer service of 1&1 is overloaded, seems that I am not the only one. 
Anyone else has problems with 1&1 server in the moment ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following permissions to the java.policy file (see link).

```
permission java.net.SocketPermission "217.72.206.68:993", "connect,resolve";
permission java.net.SocketPermission "217.72.206.68:5901-5920", "connect,resolve";
permission java.net.SocketPermission "217.72.206.68:6201-6220", "connect,resolve";
```

https://hilfe-center.1und1.de/hosting/server-c10082640/dynamic-cloud-server-linux-c10082670/java-sicherheitseintellung-verhindert-start-der-vnc-remote-konsole-a10794383.html